# how to fix Connect to sql server 2012 error?

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 connecting to SQL server 2012 through the `sqljdbc4.jar` driver.

I create an interface java class named Provider:

```
public interface Provider {
    String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-MF8EEF8;DatabaseName=db_Class_Payment;integrated Security=false;";
    String username="sa;";
    String password="123;";
}
```

and then I call Provider into the connection class named DBFactory.

```
public class DBFactory {
    static Connection con;
    static
    {
        try
        {
           Class.forName(driver);
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getcon()
    {
        return con;
    }
}
```

And then I test with this below code:

```
if(con==null){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connecting failed");
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connecting successfully.");
}
```

the process gives me with connecting failed or connection null with error msg;

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-MF8EEF8, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Class.DBFactory.<clinit>(DBFactory.java:18)
    at Frame.Home.<init>(Home.java:16)
    at Frame.Home$4.run(Home.java:449)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)
```

I already and library sqljdbc4.jar to the libraries in project.

It is still giving error result.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection `url` is wrong.

```
  integrated Security=false;
```

It should be

```
  integratedSecurity=false;
```

Read the [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017) to get better.